# How to perform a bootstrap test to compare the means of two samples?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, bootstrap

**I have two heavily skewed samples and am trying to use bootstrapping to compare their means using  t-statistic.**

What is the correct procedure to do it?

---

**The process I am using**

I am concerned about the appropriateness of using the standard error of the original/observed data in the final step when I know that this is not normally distributed.

Here are my steps:

- Bootstrap - randomly sample with replacement  (N=1000)
- Calculate t-statistic for each bootstrap to create a t-distribution:
  $$
  T(b) = \frac{(\overline{X}_{b1}-\overline{X}_{b2})-(\overline{X}_1-\overline{X}_2)  }{\sqrt{ \sigma^2_{xb1}/n + \sigma^2_{xb2}/n }}
  $$
- Estimate t confidence intervals by getting $\alpha/2$ and $1-\alpha/2$ percentiles of t-distribution
- Get confidence intervals via:

  $$
  CI_L = (\overline{X}_1-\overline{X}_2) - T\_{CI_L}.SE_{original}
  $$
  $$
  CI_U = (\overline{X}_1-\overline{X}_2) + T\_{CI_U}.SE_{original}
   $$
  where
  $$
  SE = \sqrt{ \sigma^2_{X1}/n + \sigma^2_{X2}/n }
  $$
- Look where the confidence intervals fall to determine if there is a significant difference in means (i.e. non-zero)

I have also looked at the Wilcoxon rank-sum but it is not giving very reasonable results due to the very heavily skewed distribution (e.g. the 75th == 95th percentile). For this reason I would like to explore the bootstrapped t-test further.

So my questions are:

1. Is this an appropriate methodology?
2. Is it appropriate to use the SE of observed data when I know it is heavily skewed?

---

Possible duplicate: [What method is preferred, a bootstrapping test or a nonparametric rank-based test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8642/whats-the-difference-between-bootstrapping-t-test-and-just-using-a-nonparametri)

Comment: How large are the samples?

Comment: @Michael Mayer Around 800

Comment: See also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189587

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would just do a regular bootstrap test:

- compute the t-statistic in your data and store it
- change the data such that the null-hypothesis is true. In this case, subtract the mean in group 1 for group 1 and add the overall mean, and do the same for group 2, that way the means in both group will be the overall mean.
- Take bootstrap samples from this dataset, probably in the order of 20,000.
- compute the t-statistic in each of these bootstrap samples. The distribution of these t-statistics is the bootstrap estimate of the sampling distribution of the t-statistic in your skewed data if the null-hypothesis is true.
- The proportion of bootstrap t-statistics that is larger than or equal to your observed t-statistic is your estimate of the $p$-value. You can do a bit better by looking at $($the number of bootstrap t-statistics that are larger than or equal to the observed t-statistic $+1)$ divided by $($the number of bootstrap samples $+1)$. However, the difference is going to be small when the number of bootstrap samples is large.

You can read more on that in:

- Chapter 4 of A.C. Davison and D.V. Hinkley (1997) *Bootstrap Methods and their Application*. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.
- Chapter 16 of Bradley Efron and Robert J. Tibshirani (1993) *An Introduction to the Bootstrap*. Boca Raton: Chapman & Hall/CRC.
- [Wikipedia entry on bootstrap hypothesis testing.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Bootstrap_hypothesis_testing)

Comment: This is essentially what Im doing but looking at the proportion of times the original/observed t-statistic is >= bootsrapped t-statistic. Is it ok to do a t-test on heavily skewed data in the first instance though, this is one of the reasons why I want to boostrap.

Comment: Techically, for the bootstrap test you just need a test-statistic so that is not a problem. Substantively, a t-test compares means and in skewed data medians are often more meaningful than means. So a test comparing medians instead of means may make more sense. However, that depends on your null-hypothesis, which is your choice and your choice alone.

Comment: Ok thanks, it is the mean we want to test as all our other output has been in this form.