# t test with drastically different sample sizes

Tags: t-test, sample-size, small-sample

I'm investigating if two of our processes are producing products with the same or different average measurements.

The first process has been used for a very long time and thus I have a sample size of 430 measurements for it.

The second process is very new and only has a sample size of 15 measurements for it.

I've done an F-test to compare the sample variances for what I have now, and I have no evidence to suggest the variances of the samples are different.

When I perform a t-test for the differences of averages, I get results that indicate a very significant difference between the two processes' measurements.

Is there any test out there that will achieve the goal as the t-test, but will also control for or take into account the very large sample size differences?

Comment: It's called the t-test.

Answer (score 9):

The Welch approximation t-test is designed to do the same thing as an independent samples t-test, but without relying on the assumption that the variances are equal. It is readily available in most standard statistical software. In R, it's actually the default for the `t.test` function (the argument `var.equal` controls whether a IST or Welch approximation is performed). [Here's an interesting blog post advocating for the use of a Welch approximation regardless of whether or not you think you might be violating the assumption of equal variances](http://daniellakens.blogspot.ca/2015/01/always-use-welchs-t-test-instead-of.html).

Especially if you have very unequal sample sizes, you may wish to use bootstrapping instead since it doesn't make any assumptions at all about the distribution of the sample statistic. [Here are instructions for a bootstrap t-test from another SE post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/92553/131407).

Answer (score 5):

The t-test is not dependent on equal, similar, or even close sample sizes. A t-test can be done with any sample sizes. Go ahead and use the t-test you have. I wish I knew where people got the idea that a t-test requires equal sample sizes.

Comment: Since I am using sample variances the sample size effects the sample variance.

Comment: The reason sample size matters is that unequal variances don't pose a problem for a t-test with equal sample sizes. So as long as your sample sizes are equal, you don't have to worry about homogeneity of variances. Here's a detailed explanation with simulations: [http://daniellakens.blogspot.ca/2015/01/always-use-welchs-t-test-instead-of.html](http://daniellakens.blogspot.ca/2015/01/always-use-welchs-t-test-instead-of.html)

Comment: most programming languages (eg., python) give you an error when you use unequal sample sizes. maybe that's one of the sources for the confusion